# Find users with activities in all the last 6 months

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I'm looking for the best solution on retrieving the list of users ID with activities in all the last 6 months.

Table structure and data, simplified, is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id int,
  client_id int,
  created_at timestamp
);

insert into activities values
(1, 1, '2019-06-01 00:00:00'),
(2, 2, '2019-06-01 00:00:00'), 
(3, 1, '2019-07-01 00:00:00'), 
(4, 1, '2019-08-01 00:00:00'), 
(5, 1, '2019-09-01 00:00:00'), 
(6, 1, '2019-10-01 00:00:00'), 
(7, 1, '2019-11-01 00:00:00'), 
(8, 2, '2019-11-01 00:00:00'), 
(9, 3, '2019-11-01 00:00:00');
```

I need to retrieve the list of users that has at least one activity for each one of the last 6 months. In the previous example just `client_id` 1

I thought doing a join, but it seems too expensive. I won't give you any idea on possible solutions in order not to deviate and accept whatever you have in mind.

Please, consider that I have to manage a really big data source (more then 50 millions rows).

Any quick idea?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Why would you join when there's only one table of data?

Comment: @JNevill No, this is selecting all the user that has an activity in the last 6 month, I need FOR EACH ONE the last 6 months. So, an activity in November, one in October and so on...

Comment: In that case I will point you to @Strawberry comment. Please include desired results from this sample data as it's not clear what you are after.

Comment: @jared Why wouldn't you?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e87021/2 desired result, list of all users with activities in all the last 6 months. In the example, only client_id = 1 should be selected.

Comment: cliend_id 1 does not have activity in each one of the last 6 months. June is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make no claims for the supremacy of this solution, partly because I find such requests disingenuous, but it should work, at least...

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id int,
  client_id int,
  created_at timestamp
);

insert into activities values
(1, 1, '2019-06-01 00:00:00'),
(2, 2, '2019-06-01 00:00:00'), 
(3, 1, '2019-07-01 00:00:00'), 
(4, 1, '2019-08-01 00:00:00'), 
(5, 1, '2019-09-01 00:00:00'), 
(6, 1, '2019-10-01 00:00:00'), 
(7, 1, '2019-11-01 00:00:00'), 
(8, 2, '2019-11-01 00:00:00'), 
(9, 3, '2019-11-01 00:00:00');

SELECT a.client_id 
  FROM activities a 
 WHERE a.created_at >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 MONTH)+INTERVAL 1 DAY 
 GROUP 
    BY a.client_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at,'%Y-%m'))) >= 6;
+-----------+
| client_id |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: This solution is good! Running on a table with more than 58 millions records in ClickHouse is quick and direct. I haven't thought to use a `distinct` on the format date. That was a really good idea! Thank you.